# Running Chromium on FreeBSD without window manager

Tags: freebsd, chromium

I want to run Chromium in full-screen on FreeBSD immediately when the system boots (with no graphical environment), i.e. straight from the standard text-mode boot process to a full screen Chromium browser.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this with a minimal number of packages and things to configure?

Answer (score 0):

If you have X server you could use that. Chromium requires X server as way to show you the browser. Are you using a SSH connection? If you are you need to forward X11 to the machine you are SSHing from. Since Chromium lists that as a dependency that is the minimal way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need at least the X window system (Xorg) and a window manager. There are a lot of window managers that are very configurable. You can set it up so that the window manager starts up Chromium and shows it full-screen without decoration. The details depend on the WM that you pick.

But how do you want to handle log-in and shutdown?